# How to get TIMEs of intervals between 2 given fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I have to following table, where `start_time` and `end_time` are `TIME` fields:

```
 ____________________________________
| id | day | start_time |  end_time  |
|____|_____|____________|____________|
|  1 | 1   |    8:00    |    12:00   |
```

I'd like to obtain the start time of every interval of 60 minutes between `start_time` and `end_time`, as:

```
 _______
| start |
|_______|
|  8:00 |
|  9:00 |
| 10:00 |
| 11:00 |
```

Is that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table that has integers, this is easier.  If the field were datetime, you could do it like this (for up to 7 hours):

```
select date_add(t.start_time, interval n.n hour)
from t join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
     ) n
     on date_add(t.start_time, interval n.n hour) <= t.end_time
```

With `time`, you can do it by converting to seconds and doing the arithmetic there:

```
select sec_to_time((floor(time_to_sec(t.start_time - 1)/3600)+1) + n.n*3600)
from t join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
     ) n
     on (floor(time_to_sec(t.start_time - 1)/3600)+1) + n.n*3600 <= t.end_time
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but I obtain this error: Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<='